# How to exit(close to be specific) the terminal window through Java in Linux after the termination of the Java Program

Tags: java, gnome-terminal

I've made a project in Java and I run its .jar file on the Linux terminal but after the successful termination of the program my program ends but the Terminal window did not close. I tried "java.lang.System.exit(0)", but then also the window did not close.

I'm running program by opening terminal and running `java -jar filename.jar`

I would like the terminal to exit when the Java program exits.

Comment: Be clear about how you are running this jar. Are you opening a terminal and then running `java -jar ...` (or a script that runs `java -jar ...`)? Or something else? Java's `exit` simply stops the Java main and JVM, returning the control to the starting console.

Comment: Yes, 'System.exit()' just terminates the java program, but it does not closes the terminal window, it has to be done manually. I want the terminal window to be closed the instant the program is finished.

Comment: I'm running program by opening terminal and running `java -jar filename.jar`

Answer (score 2):

As you already mention, `System.exit()` just exits the Java program,
not the invoking shell.  There are two ways to close the terminal window
after the Java program has stopped:

Either run the Java program and add the `exit` command in one line:

```
java -jar filename.jar; exit
```

This will invoke `java -jar filename.jar` and when that command returns,
the shell's `exit` command is executed (effectively closing the terminal
window).

Or *replace* the current shell with the Java process by issuing

```
exec java -jar filename.jar
```

This way the current instance of `bash` is replaced with an instance of
`java`. Hence, when the Java process stops, the terminal window will
close.

Comment: Great, it worked well!
But is there any code which when written in the program itself, closes the terminal in Ubuntu without doing the above two process which you mentioned? Just like there is this command : `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im cmd.exe") ;` for closing cmd in Windows.